# Error in appending first row of a dataframe to a csv file template

Tags: pandas, csv, shutil

Trying to append the dataframe to an existing template of a csv file.
Facing problem with the first row data only. Instead of first row being written in second row below the column fields, it is getting written adjacent to column headings with the last column heading getting merged with the first row data. Unable to resolve it. I'm seeking help to resolve this issue.

```
import shutil, pandas as pd
original_File = 'File1.csv'
target_File = "File2.csv"
shutil.copyfile(original_File, target_File)
FinalDF = pd.DataFrame()
FinalDF["Item"]= None
FinalDF["Value"] = None
FinalDF.loc["0"] = ["Book",300]
FinalDF.loc["1"] = ["Calculator",1000]
print(FinalDF)
FinalDF.to_csv('File2.csv',mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @abokey. As you rightly pointed out, may be the issue was with the default settings in macbook MS Office. It was not saving the csv file in it's own format. it might have been saving it in some other format otherthan csv. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the template file. On opening the template csv file in mac book, it was keeping the cursor active in the last column heading cell even after closing it.
When the dataframe is appended to the file2 which is a replica of File1, first row is continued from last column heading cell but succeeding rows are appended normally.
Hence i tried to open the same csv file in windows system, for the safer side, deleted all extra columns and rows in the template file and saved.
Thereafter not facing this issue.